# inventory management

Tags: inventory, group

I have "set" of product which consists of 7 pieces. 1 of each piece so only 1 set. Pieces can be sold individually so when a piece is sold, the inventory for the "set" should be 0. Likewise, if the "set" is sold, inventory for the 7 pieces should be zero. How can this be configured?

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution for your question?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you're looking for a bundled product. You can find more more about that [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/creating-a-bundled-product).
Basically a bundled product is composed of simple products. It has no stock of it's own and depends on the stock of the simple products.